# Create nuget package with shared assemblyinfo in other folder

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm working to try to get some of my companies older code into packages.  Several of the common components, considered "core", use a common file with assemblyinfo attributes from a shared folder.  The file included as a link in the project.  How do I get nuget to use the information in that file?  For example, this file contains the assembly version instead of the "assemblyinfo.cs" file in the project.  So nuget throws an error about how it can't find a replacement for the $version$ identifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done to get this to work is by using

```
nuget pack [projectFile].csproj
```

which will use the combined AssemblyInfo and the SharedAssemblyInfo file. I put both of these files in the Properties portion of the project.